# AccessViolationException with UnmanagedC++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, access-violation

I haven't worked with c++ for long, so I don't have a grasp of its intricacies quite yet. If someone could explain the reason for the following situation, it would be much appreciated.

AccessViolationException
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
// C++ Code Snippet
// unsigned int xr, xl, P
// unsigned int F(unsigned int x)
// {
//      ...
//      return (unsigned int)...
// }
```

.

```
  ...

// why does this work, but for-loop does not?
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[16];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[16 - 1];
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[14];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[14 - 1];
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[12];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[12 - 1];
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[10];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[10 - 1];
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[8];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[8 - 1];
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[6];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[6 - 1];
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[4];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[4 - 1];
xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[2];
xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[2 - 1];

/* AccessViolationException
for (int i = 16; i > 0; i -= 2)
{
    xr ^= F(xl) ^ P[i];
    xl ^= F(xr) ^ P[i - 1];
}
*/

  ...
```

FYI, this is a .dll being loaded from c#.

Comment: Memory corruption could have occurred way before any of this code is executed.  Just because it "works" when you don't loop doesn't mean the memory isn't corrupted.  It is just that the `for` loop exposed the bug to you.

Comment: P array is suppose to be 1 indexed (in C++ arrays are 0 indexed), how many elements have P? Please post the definitions of the variables in the sample code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Interesting. How does one debug that then? (As for "works", I mean it does the task it was intended to. It's (part of) a packet decrypter, and it decrypts the packets correctly (further verified via checksum). As the error occurs at runtime, not at compile-time, and only when a for-loop is used instead of writing it out manually, I have no idea what the problem is; that's why I'm asking.)

Really it comes down to this: why does the for-loop provide a different result?

Comment: @NetVipeC P has 18 elements. Posting the definitions of all variables is not feasible; it would require posting the entire source code as they are not constants.

Comment: A good debugger should show you the exact line of the error (or even pretty close if the binary is in release (with debug info)).

Comment: @user3140816 - What you're describing is classical behavior of a program that has corrupted memory.  All you're doing when you write the loop is that you're changing the binary executable.  That memory corruption bug is now moved so that it becomes exposed.  By not writing the loop, that corruption is now masked, but still exists.  I would suggest you keep the loop there and fix the problem.

Comment: @user3140816 - `Really it comes down to this: why does the for-loop provide a different result?`  Two words that exists in the 'C' and C++ languages that do not exist in most other languages: *Undefined Behavior*.  When you make runtime mistakes such as corrupt memory, write beyond the bounds of an array, etc. then anything can happen, including work, fail right away, fail on every other run, work on 1,000 computers and fail on computer 1,001, etc.